# mysql event to delete from two different tables

Tags: mysql

I have this Mysql event that runs every minute to delete records that are more than an hour old and not yet verified.

So table1 has (EXAMPLE)

```
userid | timestamp
------------------
1      | >1 Hr
2      | <1 Hr
3      | <1 Hr
4      | >1 Hr
```

So here, userid 1 & 4 will be deleted.

I also need to delete data from another table called profiles, where userid and other data are automatically inserted when a user signs up. So:

So table2 has

```
userid | ProfileName
------------------
1      | James
2      | Kirk
3      | Lars
4      | Robert
```

Here, in the above table, 1 & 4 will need to get deleted as well since they were deleted from the table above. There is no timestamp column in this table (and I cannot add one).

To delete data I do:

```
delete from table1 where rs_user_sg_ts >= date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 hour);
```

How can I delete data from both the tables in one single go using the same event?

Comment: Use MySQL triggers for this scenerio!

Comment: What storage engine do your tables use?  If `InnoDB`, [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) can automatically cascade the deletion of referenced records to the referencing ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE t1, t2
FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid 
WHERE t1.rs_user_sg_ts >= date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 hour)
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html for multiple table delete syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
  DELETE a.*, b.* 
  FROM table1 a 
  JOIN table2 b 
    ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
    WHERE a.user_id in 
            (
                  select user_id from table1 
                  where rs_user_sg_ts >= date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 hour
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should not delete from multiple tables in single query.

In case if you still interested you use below:

Multiple-table syntax:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
FROM table_references
[WHERE where_condition]
```

Refrence:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html

Hope this help !

Answer (score 0):

You can delete from multiple tables as follows:

```
delete t1,t2 
from `table1` t1, `table1`t2
where t1.userid=t2.userid
and t1.rs_user_sg_ts >= date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 hour)
```